# change ListView row xml layout resource when onListItemClick() is used

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, view, android-studio

I have this custom layout, **row.xml**  in my `ListView` rows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/swipeImageView"
        android:src="@mipmap/swipe"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:padding="11dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now I want to change **row.xml** for this layout **clicked_row.xml** when using `onListItemClick()`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/saveImageView"
        android:src="@mipmap/trash"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:padding="11dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I was trying to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18841758/4031815);  but they seem to be manipulating the visibility of views inside the layouts rather than replacing one layout for the other. I'm not sure what I should use to replace the **row.xml** for **clicked_row.xml**:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


     //Code for replacing row.xml with clicked_row.xml


}
```

Thanks on any help!

Comment: I think changing the visibility itself is sufficient for the problem. What is the exact need to switch the resource files?

Comment: @SadeshkumarPeriyasamy, the thing is I plan to include more views on **clicked_row.xml** so I though maybe it was easier to replace xmls than setting invisible 2 views and then visible other 10 views.

Comment: In that case, you can override **getItemViewTypeCount()** and **getItemViewType(int position)** of your Adapter class to have two different views. In the **onListItemClick** you can switch the type of modal and refresh the listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that better approach will be to merge the 2 files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:id="@+id/rowEditText"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/swipeImageView"
    android:src="@mipmap/swipe"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:padding="11dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And then:

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        ((ViewGroup)v).findViewById(R.id.rowTextView).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ((ViewGroup)v).findViewById(R.id.rowEditText).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)((ViewGroup)v).findViewById(R.id.swipeImageView);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(imageView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.trash));



        //Code for replacing row.xml with clicked_row.xml


    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the example this is what I also though at the beginning. I'll give it 1 or 2 days more if nobody else gives a better answer I'll acept yours anyways thanks and have your +1

Answer (score 0):

You can add both **TextView** and **ImageView** to the same layout. You can hide the visibility of one on **onListItemClick**

But this will cause the problems when you scroll the list since Android reuses the list item views. So instead of accessing the **ListItemView** directly, in your model class, add a property like **selected**.

In the **Adapater.getView()** hide/show view elements according to this **selected** field value.

This post will help you to understand how Android ListView works:
[How ListView's recycling mechanism works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works)